# Нужна ли запятая здесь?

Tags: пунктуация

Этого не было прежде(,) и этого не будет вовсе.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, нужна.

Безличные предложения в составе сложносочинённой конструкции параллельны, сказуемые выражены одним и тем же глаголом, но в разных формах. А запятая не ставится,"если части сложносочиненного предложения представляют собой безличные или неопределенно-личные предложения с одинаковой формой сказуемого". [Знаки препинания в ССП](http://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8/)

"Запятая не ставится между двумя безличными предложениями, имеющими синонимичные слова в составе сказуемых (Нужно переписать работу и объяснить допущенные в ней ошибки) [Знаки препинания в сложном предложении](http://www.yaklass.ru/materiali?mode=lsntheme&themeid=83)".

Но в нашем случае сказуемые одинаковые,а не синонимичные, общий второстепенный член отсутствует (слово "этого" употреблено дважды). Так что запятую всё-таки ставим:

***Этого не было прежде, и этого не будет вовсе.***

Для сравнения: 
***Этого не было прежде и не будет вовсе.*** Общий второстепенный член предложения "этого", запятую не ставим.